# How do you load json values with variables? [JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, country-codes

```
var code;
var Name;
$(window).on("load", function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "URL_THAT_RETURNS_JSON"
  }).done(function (json) {
    code = json.country_code;

    $(function () {
      $.ajax({
        url: "URL_THAT_RETURNS_JSON"
      }).done(function (country) {
        Name = country.code ?
      })
    })
  })
})
```

I have a variable `code` and `Name`. The top function calls json and returns this value for example: `{ .... "country_code":"US" .... }` so I put the country code value in the variable `code`. And the second ajax function will call a json file that looks like this:  `{ "AF":"Afghanistan", "AL":"Albania", ... "ZW":"Zimbabwe" }` I am trying to call the second variable with the country code I have, which is in side the `code` variable. Can I call the country code function and assign that into the `Name` variable? 

 For example => The first ajax function returned `"US"`. So the `code` variable now has `"US"` inside. Now can I in anyway call the second ajax function so that the `Name` variable will have the value `"United States"`?
But in the json file, we have `"US":"United States"`.

Comment: Depending on how the second API is called, you might just need to use square bracket notation: `Name = country[code]`

Comment: I am using a github respository, and it goes like .../countrycode.json

Comment: If your var `code` contains the code of the country (ex: AF, AL, US, etc...) and if your second ajax call returns an object like `{ "AF": "...", "AL": "...", ... }`, you should use `country[code]` to get the value for the key `code` in the object `country`. You should read about how work with javascript objects. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp

Comment: Yes! The country[code] worked, thanks everybody!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `country.code`, change it to `country[code]`.